# Completely Remove Dual-boot and Install Linux Mint

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

Currently, I am running a dual-boot with Windows 8.1 (EFI) and Linux Mint 16 Petra.

**I would like to remove both partitions and start again with a fresh distro of Linux Mint**..I am going through the Installation from a Live USB and am at the point where I should decide how to proceed with the partitioning of the system.

My machine is only recognizing the already existing Linux Mint OS, and has given me 3 options.

1. Install Linux Mint 16 Petra **alongside** Linux Mint
2. Replace Linux Mint 16 Petra with Linux Mint
3. Something Else

Option 3, which I selected when I first installed Mint alongside Windows, is where I create custom settings for each partition...

My question is, **will Windows be completely removed if I go with Option 2?**

I don't have a problem with selecting the partitions myself, but I'd rather not if I can help it...

**UPDATE: Option 2 will erase every partition on the disk and reformat for a single instance of Linux Mint. SUCCESS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: Just remove all existing partitions during the installation and do a fresh install on a newly made partition. I think you need to pick option #3 to get to do the partitioning yourself. If that's too difficult, try option #2. You can always remove Windows later and resize (expand) the existing Linux Mint partition.

*Warning:* If you delete all existing partitions, you will erase all data on the disk. Be sure to have backups of all important files, regardless of what you do with any partition! (Besides, you should have backups even if you weren't planning on reinstalling your pc.)

There might also be a "recovery" partition from your system's vendor. This contains another copy of Windows and is usually, if you didn't get a dvd, the only place from where you can install Windows again with the original serial key (after all, you probably paid for that Windows serial). If you don't care about loosing the copy of Windows that came with the system (if any), you can safely delete that partition.

Comment: I elected Option 2 with the same idea that you presented in mind..I will let you know how it goes!